# How to update the database with these checkbox values for calendar days for each user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, calendar

I am working on a calendar system that allows the person using it to select/deselect checkboxes for each day.  What i am trying to do is have the checkboxes work individually to one another for a specific user.  Currently when a checkbox is checked, no changes to the db are made. So when the page is refreshed, it returns a blank list of checkboxes for each day in the calendar. I've made a start with the work in the controller but im at a loss on what to do next.

**Controller.cs**

```
        private F2FW _db = new F2FW();

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CalendarIndex(int id, CalendarArg calArg)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            calArg.UserID = user.UserID;
            List<Event> events = new List<Event>();

            events.Add(new Event() { Title = "Exercises Uncompleted", EventDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), Type = Event.EventType.Critical });
            events.Add(new Event() { Title = "Exercises Completed", EventDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), Type = Event.EventType.Vacation });

            FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.Calendar calendar = new FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.Calendar();
            calendar.SetDate(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);   //, 10);
            calendar.View(@"~\Views\Patient\Calendar.cshtml");
            calendar.ViewData.Add("events", events);
            ViewBag.calendar = calendar.Render();

            return View(calendar);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CalendarIndex(User user, CalendarArg calArg, int dayCounter, string[] cbx_day, Patient patient, SessionExercise sessionExercise, int id)
        {
            SessionInformation sessiondata = new SessionInformation();
            Session lastsession = db.Sessions.Where(s => s.ActiveUserID == user.UserID).OrderByDescending(e => e.StartedAt).FirstOrDefault();
            calArg.CompletedToday = DateTime.Today;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (calArg.CompletionRequested == false)
                {
                    //do nothing!
                }
                else if (calArg.CompletionRequested == true)
                {
                    if (sessiondata.Completed == true)
                    {
                        if (sessionExercise.FinishedAt == calArg.Past)
                        {
                            List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
                            events.Add(new Event() { Title = "Exercises Completed", EventDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0), Type = Event.EventType.Vacation });
                            _db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
                    if (sessiondata.Completed == false)
                    {
                        if (sessionExercise.FinishedAt == calArg.Past)
                        {
                            List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
                            events.Add(new Event() { Title = "Exercises Uncompleted", EventDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0), Type = Event.EventType.Critical });
                            _db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
                }
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("CalendarIndex");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(calArg);
            }
        }
    }
    public class Event
    {
        public string Title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public DateTime EventDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public EventType Type
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public enum EventType
        {
            Appointment,
            Meeting,
            Vacation,
            Birthday,
            Personal,
            Critical
        }
    }
}
```

**Model.cs**

```
namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Models
{
    public class CalendarArg
    {
        public int CalendarDayID { get; set; }
        //------
        public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date  { get; set; }
        public bool CurrentMonth  { get; set; }

        //planner/calender
        public bool RegimeCompleted { get; set; }
        public bool CompletionRequested { get; set; }
        public DateTime CompletedToday { get; set; }
        public DateTime Future { get; set; }
        public DateTime Past { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        void ThePast(CalendarArg calArg)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now <= calArg.Date)
            {
                Past = calArg.Past;
            }
        }
        void TheFuture(CalendarArg calArg)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now >= calArg.Date)
            {
                Future = calArg.Future;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**View.cshtml**

```
@model FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.CalendarArg
@{
    CalendarArg calArg = this.Model;
    List<FaceToFaceWebsite.Controllers.Event> events = (List<FaceToFaceWebsite.Controllers.Event>)ViewData["events"];


    string cssClass = calArg.CurrentMonth == true ? "cell1" : "cell2";
}

@if (calArg.Date.Day == calArg.SelectedDate.Day)
{
    cssClass += " selected_day";
}

@if (calArg.Date.Day == calArg.Date.Day)
{
    if (DateTime.Now <= calArg.Date)
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CompletionRequested, new { @checked = calArg.CompletionRequested });
    }
}
        <div class="@cssClass">
            <h2>@calArg.Date.Day.ToString()</h2>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            @foreach (var evt in events)
            {
                if (evt.EventDate.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") == calArg.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
                {
                    <div class="evt @evt.Type.ToString()">@evt.Title</div>
                }
            }
        </div>
```